# angularJS $scope change not updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been banging my head against an angularJS $scope issue. I have an array that I update in a controller function. According to my console logs, the values inside it are indeed changed. However, the view is not updated. Here are the snippets.

```
//array initialisation

    $scope.fieldSuggestions = []

//modifying function

  $scope.changeCurrentInput = function(fieldName, eye) {
    for(var field in $scope.test){
      console.log($scope.test[field].name)
      if($scope.test[field].name === fieldName){
        console.log($scope.test[field].values)
        console.log("be4 update")
        console.log($scope.fieldSuggestions)
        $scope.fieldSuggestions = $scope.test[field].values;
        console.log("after update")
        console.log($scope.fieldSuggestions)
      }
    }
  };

//view

 <div ng-repeat="choice in fieldSuggestions">       
    <button class="button button-positive">{{choice}}</button>
</div>
```

MORE DETAILS...

I think this might be relevant. I have a parent view, and several child views. Each of these routes use the same controller. i.e: the property controller in routes.js is the same for all. The button that calls the modifying function is in the child views, but the ng-repeat that does not get updated is in the parent view.

Comment: What happens if you push or splice in the list? Is the view updated then?

Comment: @Patrick no the view is not updated with push either.

Comment: Are you changing the value in a digest cycle? How and when are you calling the function?

Comment: @Patrick I am calling the function from a ng-click on a button. See the extra details i posted in the question.

Comment: Uhm, okay. If you are "sharing" variables you should use a service, in order to get the same variable reference between your controllers. If they inherit from each other, you need to put the variable inside a "model" variable, i.e. `$scope.model = { fieldSuggestions: [] }` in order to avoid [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Comment: @Patrick can I please get more details about where to put this declaration and then how to access fieldSuggestions. I am fairly new to angularJS. Thank You very much.

Comment: You access it by just prefixing fieldSuggestions with `model.`, there's nothing special with it. If you want further assistance I suggest that you create a jsfiddle or a plunkr project and link to it.

Comment: @Patrick replaced `$scope.fieldSuggestions = []`  with `$scope.model = { fieldSuggestions: [] }` and changed the accessors and ng repeat accordingly with no success.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question with more details on how you've set everything up? At the moment it is difficult determining what the exact error is. Also, if you can create a fiddle or plunkr that would also help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was shadowing the parent fieldSuggestions variable by declaring my child controllers as being the same one as the parent. The solution was to not redeclare the controller on the child routes as it sees the parent one automatically.

Thanks everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Due to fact that you are changing nested properties Angular is not triggering digests. You can simply fix that by adding in `link` or `controller` function:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('fieldSuggestions', function(newFieldSuggestions, oldFieldSuggestions) {
  $scope.fieldSuggestions= newFieldSuggestions;
});
```

Things to point out: That may be not the most optimal for large collections and complex objects.

Comment: where do I add this? Tried a few spots without success. And are you sure that i'm "changing nested properties"? I'm not modifying $scope.test, i'm modifying $scope.fieldSuggestions.

Comment: Inside your `controller`/`link` function in directive.

Comment: thank you for your time but it doesnt seem to work. I added it in my controller functions. right after angular.module('examWriteCtrl', []).controller('examWriteCtrl', ['$scope', ...

Answer (score 0):

I think because of nesting change it can't update the value at that time.You can use $scope.$apply() to get the latest updated value 
Like....  $scope.$apply($scope.fieldSuggestions = $scope.test[field].values);